# Merge sort segmentation Fault NASM

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm, coredump

Hi I am trying to implement a mergesort algorithm in nasm on linux, but I am getting a segmentation fault, so I typed in konsole this "gdb mergesort core" and I got this

```
"El núcleo se generó por «./mergesort».
 El programa terminó con la señal 11, Segmentation fault.
 #0  0x080481a5 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
 #0  0x080481a5 in ?? ()
 #1  0x080481b1 in ?? ()
 #2  0x080480af in ?? ()"
```

but I don`t really understand what to do with it or where the segmentation fault is taking place. Could anyone help me please?

Im sorry this is my first time pasting code here so I don`t know how to indent everything the way it should

The code in NASM is the following:

```
BITS 32
extern printf
    section .data
    section .text
  global _start

  global main,
main:
  _start:

nop;
mov edi, sorted
mov esi, array
mov ecx, 10
rep movsd

push 10
push 0
push sorted
call mergesort
add esp, 12

push sorted
push 10
call print
add esp, 8
ret

merge:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
push eax
push ecx
push edx
push edi
push esi



mov ecx, [ebp+20]
sub ecx, [ebp+12]

shl DWORD[ebp+12], 2
shl DWORD[ebp+16], 2
shl DWORD[ebp+20], 2

mov edx, temp       
mov edi, [ebp+8]    
add edi, [ebp+16]   



mov esi, [ebp+8]
add [ebp+12], esi
add [ebp+16], esi
add [ebp+20], esi
mov esi, [ebp+12]

.next:

cmp esi, [ebp+16]
jnz .second

cmp edi, [ebp+20]
jnz .first

jmp .end



.first:
cmp esi, [ebp+16]
jnz .second


mov eax, [edi]
mov [edx], eax
add edx, 4
add edi, 4
jmp .next

.second:
cmp edi, [ebp+20]
jnz .third


mov eax, [esi]
mov [edx], eax
add edx, 4
add esi, 4
jmp .next

.third:
mov eax, [esi]
cmp eax, [edi]
jnl .forth


mov [edx], eax
add edx, 4
add esi, 4
jmp .next

.forth:
mov eax, [edi]
mov [edx], eax
add edi, 4
add edx, 4
jmp .next
.end:



mov esi, temp
mov edi, [ebp+12]
rep movsd


pop esi
pop edi
pop edx
pop ecx
pop eax
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret

mergesort:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
push eax

mov eax, DWORD[ebp+16]  
sub eax, [ebp+12]   
cmp eax, 2
JL .end
    push edx
    push ebx
        xor edx, edx
        mov ebx, 2
        div ebx
    pop ebx
    pop edx
    add eax, [ebp+12]   


    push eax        
    push DWORD[ebp+12]  
    push DWORD[ebp+8]   
    call mergesort
    add esp, 12

    push DWORD[ebp+16]  
    push eax        
    push DWORD[ebp+8]   
    call mergesort
    add esp, 12

    push DWORD[ebp+16]  
    push eax        
    push DWORD[ebp+12]  
    push DWORD[ebp+8]   
    call merge
    add esp, 16
.end:
pop eax
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret


print:
push ebp    
mov ebp, esp
push ecx
push edx

mov edx, [ebp+12]
mov ecx, [ebp+8]

.args:
    push ecx
    push edx
    push DWORD[edx]
    push format
    call print
    add esp, 8
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    add edx, 4
LOOP .args

push endl
call print
add esp, 4

pop edx     
pop ecx     
mov esp, ebp    
pop ebp     
ret     

format:
db  ' %2d', 0
endl:
db  10, 0

array:
dd  10, 9, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1


section .bss
sorted:
resd    10
temp:
resd    10
```

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you have data defined in the `code` section?
This:

```
format:
db  ' %2d', 0
endl:
db  10, 0

array:
dd  10, 9, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1
```

should be in your `.data` section.

Add debug symbols to your object file by adding `-F stabs` to the command line for NASM (In Linux that is) I am unsure of the option for Windows.
`nasm -f elf -F stabs $(APP).asm`

This will show you your function names in the gdb backtrace.

The problem seems to be in your `print` function, look at it *carefully*!  You are recursively calling it.

```
print:
    push    ebp    
    mov     ebp, esp
    push    ecx
    push    edx

    mov edx, [ebp+12]
    mov ecx, [ebp+8]

.args:
    push    ecx
    push    edx

    push    DWORD[edx]
    push    format
    call    print ; <<<<<<<<<<
    add     esp, 8

    pop     edx
    pop     ecx

    add     edx, 4
    LOOP    .args

    push    endl
    call    print ; <<<<<<<<<<
    add     esp, 4

    pop     edx     
    pop     ecx     
    mov     esp, ebp    
    pop     ebp     
    ret
```

I think you mean to call `printf`

```
print:
    push    ebp    
    mov     ebp, esp
    push    ecx
    push    edx

    mov     edx, [ebp+12]
    mov     ecx, [ebp+8]

.args:
    push    ecx
    push    edx

    push    DWORD[edx]
    push    format
    call    printf
    add     esp, 8

    pop     edx
    pop     ecx

    add     edx, 4
    LOOP    .args

    push    endl
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4

    pop     edx     
    pop     ecx     
    mov     esp, ebp    
    pop     ebp     
    ret
```

See the difference?  Fix that issue and it seems to print out correctly!
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the print and printf issue, I`ve already fixed it, but now I`m getting an undefined reference to printf, what is that??

Comment: Looks like you got your code from https://github.com/hugopeixoto/mergesort/blob/master/assembly/mergesort.asm  did you Assemble and Link with the commands on line 2 and 3 of that code?